# Select the smallest value from a selection using ArcMap SQL selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql

I am trying to select the smallest Directionality value based on a selection of two Workingspace values:

[image]

In the above picture, there are two "Jeffery's" selected, I want to then select the Jeffery with Directionality 2 (I.E. the smaller one) without using = 2. I know there is a max/ min SQL expression:

```
DIRECTIONALITY = (SELECT MIN( DIRECTIONALITY) FROM TableName)
```

But this returns no values when choosing the select from current selection method.
HOWEVER, if I create a new selection, this SQL does return a selection of 1 (it selects the row where Directionality is 1).

Is there a way to tell ArcMap to select the smallest value of a previous selection based on a different field? Specifically in Model Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current SQL expression does not return anything from the current selection because `(SELECT MIN( DIRECTIONALITY) FROM TableName)` always evaluates to `1`, which is indeed the minimum value for the whole table. You need to take the minimum value from just the rows that meet the condition `WORKINGSPACE = 'Jeffery'` and you can do this in one selection instead of two. The following expression (which I am sure can be rewritten in a cleaner way) worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE DIRECTIONALITY = (SELECT MIN(DIRECTIONALITY) FROM TableName WHERE WORKINGSPACE = 'Jeffery')
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked!!

Comment: @Sarah Glad to help. If it solved your question, you can mark this answer as the accepted answer.